# How can i customize the export personal data file?

Tags: database, users, export

I want to know is there a way to customize the export personal data page? If you go to wp dashboard > tools > export personal data, you can download an html file which contains your personal data. Is there a way to customize that page through code or by using a plugin. Thanks and please help.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the layout is hard-coded in `/wp-admin/includes/file.php` (look for `wp_privacy_generate_personal_data_export_file()`) and there is no filter hook to change it.